# Angular HttpClient cannot get response

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I am failing to get any server response for this post request:

```
 this.httpClient
            .post(this.appConfigService.buildAuthorizationUrl('/logon'), data, {
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                //observe: 'response',
            })
            .toPromise()
            .then(
                (response: any) => {
                                // not reached
                },
                (error: any) => {
                                // not reached
                }
            )
            .catch(ex => {
               // not reached
            });
```

**UPDATE:**
**Fiddler shows the server response that I would expect to get in the 
`.then` success block:**

A server response example:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache,no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache,no-cache
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Expires: -1,0
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcS2F5IFphbmRlclxEb2N1bWVudHNcZXZlXFNvdXJjZVxJbmZvcnNIVC5HZW5lc2lzQXBpXGxvZ29u?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Date: Wed, 30 Oct 2019 10:33:16 GMT
Content-Length: 79

{"error":"Error","error_description":"The user name or password is incorrect."}
```

**UPDATE**
could this because of headers

```
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
```

instead of

```
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
```

background: 
I am migrating and existing angularjs app to angular and I use the same (unchanged) API

Comment: It seems the provided user name and password is incorrect

Comment: Question says it all "{"error":"Error","error_description":"The user name or password is incorrect."}"

Comment: Did you use the correct credentials?

Comment: Check what you are sending as `data`. Apparently it's wrong.

Comment: Obviously I need to clarify for some users -> Update

Comment: usually the bad request (400 error code) occurs if the request json is invalid. May be keys are not correct or values are not valid.

Comment: The question is not about the result but about why the result cannot be fetched in angular! Please reade the text!

Answer (score 0):

Problem was caused by CORS issue